# What's hook_node_view() alternative?

Tags: nodes, hooks, 8

I am using Drupal 8 Beta 14 and I want to edit the node object in teaser view mode. As `hook_node_view` is removed in Drupal 8. What's the alternative hook or some other way that I can use to edit the node? Is it `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view` or `hook_entity_view` or some other thing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`hook_node_view()` hasn't really been removed, the way it's invoked has just changed. As you mentioned, it's now handled by [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view/8).

So you can either use:

```
hook_entity_view()
```

or

```
hook_node_view()
```

The latter would make more sense if you're targeting nodes specifically.

Comment: Thank you Clive, `hook_node_view` is picked. But I'm wondering where is it defined? I could find it only in NodeRSSContentTest.php file. Secondly `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view` never gets called, no matter what I do. Why is it so?

Comment: Because `ENTITY_TYPE` is a placeholder - it needs to be replaced with the actual entity type (so it would be `hook_node_view` for a node, `hook_user_view` for a user, `hook_profile2_view` for a profile2 entity, and so on)

Answer (score 10):

Here is the example for `hook_node_view` in D8 version 8.1.1

```
function mymodule_node_view(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
   $build['body'][0]['#text'] = 'this is a new altered content body ';
}
```