# Can't find cookie for validation in EventSubscriber

Tags: 8, cookies, event-subscribers

There's this module [Splash Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/splash_redirect) in which `src/EventSubscriber/SplashRedirectEventSubscriber.php` is supposed to check if the cookie `$config_cookie` exists or not, if it already exists then the user continues onto the requested node (`$config_source`), but if it does *not* exist then the user is sent to `$config_destination` and it creates the cookie (`$config_cookie`).

It succeeds in creating the `$config_cookie` and the redirect to `$config_destination` but it never seems to acknowledge the existence of the cookie once created and continues to redirect the user to `$config_destination`.

Any clues? On Drupal 8.6

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\splash_redirect\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse;

/**
 * Splash redirect Event Subscriber.
 */
class SplashRedirectEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  /**
   * Triggered when system sends response.
   */
  public function modifyIntercept(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    $config = \Drupal::config('splash_redirect.settings');
    $config_enabled = $config->get('splash_redirect.is_enabled');
    $config_source = $config->get('splash_redirect.source');
    $config_destination = $config->get('splash_redirect.destination');
    $config_cookie = $config->get('splash_redirect.cookie_name');
    $config_duration = $config->get('splash_redirect.duration');

    // If splash config is not enabled then we don't need to do any of this.
    if ($config_enabled == 1) {
      // Current request from client.
      $request = \Drupal::request();
      $current_uri = $request->getRequestUri();
      $http_host = $request->getHost();
      // Current response from system.
      $response = $event->getResponse();
      $route = (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) ? \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')->id() : null;
      $has_cookie = $request->cookies->has($config_cookie);

      // If splash-cookie has not been set, and user requesting 'source' page,
      // set cookie and redirect to splash page.
      if ($config_source == $route) {
        // Kill cache on this route or else cookie might not be read with VCL.
        \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();

        if (!$has_cookie) {
          // Set redirect response with cookie and redirect location.
          $redir = new TrustedRedirectResponse($config_destination, '302');
          $cookie = new Cookie($config_cookie, 'true', strtotime('now + ' . $config_duration . 'days'), '/', '.' . $http_host, false, true);
          $redir->headers->setCookie($cookie);
          $redir->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=0');
          $redir->addCacheableDependency($config_destination);
          $event->setResponse($redir);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    // Listen for response event from system and intercept.
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['modifyIntercept'];
    return $events;
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you check that the cookie exists in your browser's "inspect element/inspect" window? If it's not there you might wanna check if your browser settings has allow sites to set & read cookie data.

Comment: @NoSssweat Yes the cookie is created and exists (via the inspect window).  I have a suspicion now that this is due to the fact that the cookie that is successfully set is not being successfully read - perhaps due to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432281/symfony2-read-cookie that says reading a cookie needs to be done in a Request... but I don't know how to implement that here to test.

Comment: Have you considered storing your value & time of entry in a session variable instead?

Comment: No, I haven't @NoSssweat. The end result here is a that the anonymous user is shown a splash page of temporary content once every X days (set in the cookie, for when the cookie expires, the user is shown the temporary content again).  I haven't used Drupal session variables and would it work in this case, it seems like a cookie is the better way to go?

Comment: Yeah, cookie is the way to go here. If these are nodes, you could try doing the redirect in [hook_node_view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/203966/27710)

Comment: This is really close to working - everything works up to the point where I need to verify the cookie that was successfully set. I don't think I need to run down another path just yet.

Comment: ok, try retrieving the cookie [like this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp) and see if that makes any diff.

Comment: @NoSssweat Okay tested that and also var_dump the $request->header and both show that the cookie is NOT set. However, in my browser inspector (Chrome and Firefox) I can see the cookie sitting there, set with a value of true. I can go to chrome settings and delete the cookie and it gets set again. I'm trying to work out the disconnect between the $request->header->setCookie creating a cookie but not creating it in the $request->header... oh boy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some ideas:

Like for the config you have to add a cache dependency for the cookie, too:

```
  $response->getCacheableMetadata()->addCacheContexts(['cookies:' . $config_cookie]);
```

Or use an uncacheable `RedirectResponse` to simplify things.

And try to set a priority for the event subscriber, for example 31, because your code depends only on routing, which has 32:

```
  $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['modifyIntercept', 31];
```

You don't need to get a response in an request subscriber, because there isn't one yet. Get the request instead and make sure that you are in a master request. So this would be how the subscriber starts most times:

```
  public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
      return;
    }
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    ...
```

---

Simplifying a bit more and using dummy values for testing:

```
  public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
      return;
    }
    $route_match = \Drupal::routeMatch();
    if (!$route_match->getRouteName() == 'entity.node.canonical') {
      return;
    }
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    if ($route_match->getRawParameter('node') == '1') {
      \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
      if (!$request->cookies->has('foo')) {
        $redirect = new RedirectResponse($request->getBasePath() . '/node/2', 302);
        $redirect->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('foo', '123', '+30 seconds'));
        $event->setResponse($redirect);
      }
    }
  }
```

This is working on my local dev environment.

---

Complete code (including dependency injection and code updated to D9/10):

*/src/EventSubscriber/MymoduleSubscriber.php*

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;

/**
 * mymodule event subscriber.
 */
class MymoduleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  /**
   * The route match.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface
   */
  protected $routeMatch;

  /**
   * Constructs event subscriber.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface $route_match
   *   The route match.
   */
  public function __construct(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    $this->routeMatch = $route_match;
  }

  /**
   * Kernel request event handler.
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent $event
   *   The request event.
   */
  public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event) {
    if (!$event->isMainRequest()) {
      return;
    }
    if (!$this->routeMatch->getRouteName() == 'entity.node.canonical') {
      return;
    }
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    if ($this->routeMatch->getRawParameter('node') == '1') {
      \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
      if (!$request->cookies->has('foo')) {
        $redirect = new RedirectResponse($request->getBasePath() .'/node/2', 302);
        $redirect->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('foo', '123', '+30 seconds'));
        $event->setResponse($redirect);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return [
      KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['onKernelRequest', 31],
    ];
  }

}
```

*mymodule.services.yml*

```
services:
  mymodule.event_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber\MymoduleSubscriber
    arguments: ['@current_route_match']
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Comment: Dumped in your code above - thank you for this. I'm still getting a redirect on every request for `node/1`. Is it possible to get your complete working code from the top so I can test that? Just to get all the moving parts - eg: are you using `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;`?

Comment: I've transferred the code to another Drupal site in a new module and it is working there as well, see the complete code sample.

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the answer. I'm marking this as answered since you have it working on 2 environments. However my environment is still having issues and forwarding me persistently to the redirect (node/2 in your modules case) despite the cookie successfully showing up in my dev tools.  I'm on a pantheon.io environment on a fresh install. Maybe it is a pantheon.io / lando problem? PHP 7.2? I can't work it out.. I've tried on 3 browsers across 2 machines. I'll have to try debug the environment I guess.

Comment: Confirming this now works in my environment as long as cookie name is prefixed with `SESS` on Pantheon/Lando environment - eg `SESSfoo`. This code is tight. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Original [splash_redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/splash_redirect) module dev here. Thanks for joining me in the caching rabbit hole! (Sorry, can't make 'comments' yet so I have to put this in an answer)

Thanks to @4k4 for the great suggestions, I will likely implement some of those in the next release, but OP's issue looks to be specific to Pantheon's global CDN, which sets the `Vary: cookie` header, and caches the source redirect.

*So, if you're using splash_redirect on Pantheon, [please prefix your Splash Cookie name with "SESS"](https://pantheon.io/docs/caching-advanced-topics/#using-your-own-session-style-cookies), e.g. `SESSsplash` *

Comment: Wow. That you @AdamB. - Can also confirm you cannot have underscores in the cookie on Pantheon. It should be `SESScookiename` not `SESScookie_name`.  Both this module and splash_redirect module now work as expected. THANK YOU BOTH! Glad also that module maintainer for splash_redirect can pull some ideas from stellar work by @4k4.