# How do I set a cookie using $response->headers->setCookie() in a form submission handler?

Tags: 8, cookies

I read on [Deprecate user_cookie_save() and user_cookie_delete().](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2603140) that `user_cookie_save()` will be deprecated in Drupal 9 and that we should now use the Symfony's method, as in the following code.

```
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('foo', 'bar'));
return $response->send();
```

If I use that code in a submission handler of a custom form, `$response-send()` just returns an empty page, rather than my site. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't send a response from custom code in Drupal. You have to return it from a controller.

You can also set a response or add the cookie to an existing response in an event subscriber. In your case set the response in form submit, then Drupal does this for you in a core event subscriber:

```
$form_state->setResponse($response);
```

To avoid the empty page you probably want to fill the response with content or add the cookie to a redirect response to display a different page.

---

**Don't `$response->send()`**

To explain why not to send a response. When you find a code example for the Symfony component [HttpFoundation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html) sending a response, it isn't valid for custom code in Drupal. See the warning in this doc:

> This article explains how to use the HttpFoundation features as an
>   independent component in any PHP application. In Symfony applications
>   everything is already configured and ready to use. Read the Controller
>   article to learn about how to use these features when creating
>   controllers.

In addition the Drupal kernel is wrapped in stack middlewares using [Stack/Builder](https://github.com/stackphp/builder). So sending a response can even be a security risk if you have for example installed a middleware providing security checks.

Comment: I moved my cookie setting to a controller method and edited the original question.

Comment: In the controller `return $response;` is all you need to do, don't `$response->send();`. I tried to make it more clear in the answer. About the Pantheon/Lando environment, there might be a naming issue for the cookie, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/274485/cant-find-cookie-for-validation-in-eventsubscriber

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I had been on a page in the Pantheon docs about cookies, but it didn't mention the SESS prefix was needed. What a nightmare that was.